# How to make transaction from ipad app to braintree server

Tags: ios, ipad, payment-gateway, braintree

I am using braintree payment gateway in my ipad app. I have integrated BT sdk to my app and i am able to make sandbox testing. But i didnt get to know, how to initiate transaction from my app i.e.,There is no classes or methods for making transactions. Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you need more help than can easily be provided here, please [reach out to our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

The iOS app is responsible for getting the credit card information to your server. It is up to your server to [create transactions](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby/transactions/create) and send them on to Braintree:

```
result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
  :amount => "10.00",
  :credit_card => {
    :number => params[:encrypted_card_number],
    :expiration_month => params[:encrypted_expiration_month],
    :expiration_year => params[:encrypted_expiration_year]
  }
)
```

Follow any of our [guides](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby/guide/overview) for more help with the server side integration.